# DDD paradigm. Is it possible to use a service from the Infrastructure layer on the Application Core.Domain layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Sorry for my English, I am writing a real estate appraisal module and decided to try writing in the DDD paradigm.
I looked at examples and different articles and formed the following picture for myself (simplified):

1. `ApplicationCore.Domain` - the core of business logic, contains all the necessary objects divided into 2 typesа
   `Entitys` - if an entity needs to be stored in a database and it is a ready-made complete business logic object.
   `ValueObjects` - all other properties that encapsulate the behavior, are compared by the value of the fields, and are part of Entity
   It is very important to create only valid objects, so I create everything through factories with a validator, and the constructors are private.
   There should be no references to other dependencies, as isolated as possible.
2. `ApplicationCore.App` - a layer above `ApplicationCore.Domain`, contains a link to it.
   works with objects from `ApplicationCore.Domain` and uses external services through `Port/Adapte`r.
   `Port` - For example, an abstraction of a repository, its implementation through an `Adapter` on the `Infrastructure` layer.
   interaction logic for ApplicationCore is in AppServices - for classic implementation or in Command / Request - for CQRS
3. `Infrastructure` - contains a link to `ApplicationCore.Domain` and `ApplicationCore.App`.
   Implements the ports of the `ApplicationCore.App` layer

[image]

Entities are independent from each other and refer to each other by keys for interaction.
I kept the basic logic of the assessment system in this paradigm.
But here it was necessary to add a service that receives additional information for evaluation from different sources, while in wiretapping mode.
Those. Works against the background of listening to TcpIp socket

Service settings are stored in the database and change frequently - i.e. you need to introduce a new `Entity`
A chain is formed

```
DataProvider (ApplicationCore.Domain) -> IDataProviderRepository (ApplicationCore.App) -> EfDataProviderRepository (Infrastructure).
```

`DataProvider` - must depend on `ITcpIpTransport`, without it it is just a set of settings for `TcpIpTransport`.
Logically, `DataProvider` is a service for receiving data, but it has settings and state stored in the database, i.e. you need to make it `Entity`.
If you make the `DataProvider` dependent on the `Infrastructure` layer, then `ApplicationCore.Domain` will also have ports to external services, is this permissible?

how best to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to admit that is a bit hard to understand everything. Especially at the end, you speak about object that isn't clear where they are and what they do.

Anyway, you cannot use anything for the layer above (infrastructure) into the layers below (application and domain). I don't know how would you do it, but as a simple dependency it would not leave you compile any project. You'll end with a circular dependency.

Given that you would not do this, you can build a service (I do it with static functions to avoid any kind of unwanted implementation) into the domain layer. That service use interfaces that are implemented into the application layer. Into the application layer you'll also use (or reuse) interfaces that will be implemented into the infrastructure layer.

Comment: I think the question is more accurate, the service is needed at the domain level, the service has a dependency, to create which you need to extract the settings from the database. If the dependency settings are not dynamic, but are known at the start of the application, as the database settings or Exchange Queues, then such a service is registered in the DY with the known settings, and then it is simply used by the application-level services. I need a domain-level service that has a dependency, for the creation of which I need an entity from the domain.